# Como puedo procesar con colas de laravel peticiones put masivas a un webservice?

Tags: php, laravel, webservice, jobs

Tengo un conjunto de registros en una tabla que necesito enviar a un webservice y quiero hacerlo con colas de laravel. La idea es que cada vez que genere un registro, se active la cola para que se procese el put en background y asi tener una mejor experiencia de usuario. En el handle, leo la tabla y hago el put por cada registro pero no hace nada. No se si este tipo de proceso es viable o compatible con esta funcionaldiad de laravel.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=<nombre-cola>
```

Y ya con eso debería iniciar a procesar lo que necesites ;)